# Expectation in restricted bivariate distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, bivariate-distributions

I'm trying to follow the solution of this exercise: [link](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_3_solved_probs.php).

It says: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two jointly continuous random variables with joint PDF

$
\begin{equation}
\nonumber f_{XY}(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
2 & \quad y+x \leq 1, x>0, y>0 \\
& \quad \\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
$

To find $E[X]$, I would expect it to be:

$E[X] = \int_{0}^{1-y}{2dx}$

And have $E[X]$ be a function of $y$.

But the solution actualy integrates the function over $y$ to get a function of $x$ and then integrate again to get $E[X]$:

$
\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber f_X(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dy \\
\nonumber &=\int_{0}^{1-x}2dy\\
\nonumber &=2(1-x).
\end{align}
$

$
\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber E[X]&=\int_{0}^{1}2x(1-x)dx\\
\nonumber &=\frac{1}{3}=EY,
\end{align}
$

What is the idea behind integrating a bivariate $PDF_{x,y}$ before integrating to calculate the $E[X]$.

Comment: Replacing an earlier, now deleted, comment ... $E[X] := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, x f_{XY}(x, y)\, dx \, dy.$ With the integration over $y$ first this reduces to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, x f_{X}(x)\, dx$ where $f_X(x) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, f_{XY}(x, y)\, dy.$

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of $X$ is a number here, which we compute by first finding the marginal distribution of $X$ (hence the integration over the joint density for all possible values of $X$). From the probability distribution of a random variable...we can compute its expectation (if it exists).

I don't see any reason it would be a function of $Y$.